# dynamic creation of checkboxes based on retrieved database

Tags: java, jsp, struct

I have a table that stores the values of labels both in English and French. How to show dynamic checkboxes based on that labels as checkboxes in JSP Structs

In the action class, I get a list of values. How to get them populated on JSP?

[image]

expected [image]

Comment: To submit chechboxes they need to be checked. You can find the same answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16877697/573032).

Comment: Welcome. You should take a look at [ask] and take the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour, if you have not done so already